# Mysql Regexp to search record contain some specific words

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to use mysql to select all records are having **ONLY**

these words on it:

**4ahhyes4,4ahh4,4ahaa4 , white space and dot.**

here's my query.

```
SELECT * FROM p_posts WHERE post_content REGEXP '^(4ahhyes4|4ahh4|4ahaa4|\.|\s)+$';
```

but it match all records with other character (just like LIKE syntax):

```
abcde 4ahhyes4 4ahhyes4 4ahhyes4 ~> failed because abcde
123sdasd 4ahhyes4 ..... ~> failed because 123sdasd
4ahhyes4 4ahhyes4.... ..... ~> OK
```

how to match only record containing these words on it ONLY ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under the definition of the [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator:

> **Note**
>   Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “**`\n`**” to represent the newline character), you must double any “**`\`**” that you use in your [**`REGEXP`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)  strings.

The documentation on [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html) explains:

> MySQL recognizes the escape sequences shown in [Table 9.1, “Special Character Escape Sequences”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences). For all other escape sequences, backslash is ignored. That is, the escaped character is interpreted as if it was not escaped. For example, “**`\x`**” is just “**`x`**”.

Therefore, the pattern you are currently matching against is `^(4ahhyes4|4ahh4|4ahaa4|.|s)+$`.  You should instead do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   p_posts
WHERE  post_content REGEXP '^(4ahhyes4|4ahh4|4ahaa4|\\.|\\s)+$'
```

Comment: tks. here's my completed syntax: 
    ^(4ahhyes4|4ahh4|4ahaa4|\\.|[[:space:]])+$
\\s is seems not work with mysql?

Answer (score -1):

`WHERE post_content IN ( '4ahhyes4', '4ahh4', '4ahaa4', 'white space and dot' )` isn't?